# Looping the performance tests

Tags: powershell, performance-testing

I have the following code to be executed from a file infinitely. The list file has only 5 records for testing purpose. For performance, I wanted to execute the test overnight with the same data over and over again. Please suggest how to increment the executions.

```
list.txt file has the following records :
microsoft.com
twitter.com
facebook.com
amazon.com
google.com

$InputFile = 'C:\Temp\list.txt'
$addresses = get-content $InputFile
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $InputFile

    while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){ $TotalIPs++ }
    write-Host $TotalIPs
    write-host    ""    
    write-Host "Executing nslookup query for all ..."    
        foreach($address in $addresses) {
            ## Progress bar
            $i++
            <# $percentdone = (($i / $TotalIPs) * 100)
            $percentdonerounded = "{0:N0}" -f $percentdone
            Write-Progress -Activity "Executing nslookup queries" -CurrentOperation "Performing on IP: $address (IP $i of $TotalIPs)" -Status "$percentdonerounded% complete" -PercentComplete $percentdone #>
            ## End progress bar
            try {
                [system.net.dns]::resolve($address) | Select HostName,AddressList
                }
                catch {
                    Write-host "$address was not found. $_" -ForegroundColor Green
                }
           }



    write-host    ""            
    write-Host "Pinging each address..."
        foreach($address in $addresses) {
            ## Progress bar
            $j++
            $percentdone2 = (($j / $TotalIPs) * 100)
            $percentdonerounded2 = "{0:N0}" -f $percentdone2
            Write-Progress -Activity "Performing pings" -CurrentOperation "Pinging IP: $address (IP $j of $TotalIPs)" -Status "$percentdonerounded2% complete" -PercentComplete $percentdone2
            ## End progress bar
                if (test-Connection -ComputerName $address -Count 2 -Quiet ) 
{  
                    write-Host "$address responded" -ForegroundColor Green 
                    } else 
                    { Write-Warning "$address does not respond to pings"              
                    }  
        }
write-host    ""        
write-host "Complete!"
```

Comment: When you say "for performance", what exactly are you hoping to assess? Limited memory consumption?

Comment: Looping the file content over and over again. We have to run on our clients to verify the duration test.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - I am running the duration test for a span of Week. My aim is to application run continuously without any stoppage for that I am checking, memory, counters and storage also want to see how the garbage collection is implemented. I have the data with Alexa 1M Urls. I want to run a max of 4M urls to check the process speed as well.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - If I need to verify Memory leak, how should I change the code ? Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would set total number of IPs to 0 at the beginning.
Second, I would put a while loop which never ends to loop between the addresses you provided in your text file.
Third, I would set $j to 0 in the end per each cycle.

This is a bit modified code you posted:

```
$InputFile = 'C:\Temp\list.txt'
$addresses = get-content $InputFile
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $InputFile
$TotalIPs = 0

while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){ $TotalIPs++ }
write-Host $TotalIPs
write-host    ""    
write-Host "Executing nslookup query for all ..."    

While($true)
{
    foreach($address in $addresses) 
    {
        ## Progress bar
        $i++

        ## End progress bar
        try 
        {
            [system.net.dns]::resolve($address) | Select HostName,AddressList
        }
        catch 
        {
            Write-host "$address was not found. $_" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }

    write-host    ""            
    write-Host "Pinging each address..."
    foreach($address in $addresses) {
    ## Progress bar

    $j++
    $percentdone2 = (($j / $TotalIPs) * 100)
    $percentdonerounded2 = "{0:N0}" -f $percentdone2

    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing pings" -CurrentOperation "Pinging IP: $address (IP $j of $TotalIPs)" -Status "$percentdonerounded2% complete" -PercentComplete $percentdone2

    ## End progress bar
    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $address -Count 2 -Quiet ) 
        {  
            write-Host "$address responded" -ForegroundColor Green 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Write-Warning "$address does not respond to pings"              
        }  
    }
    $j = 0

    write-host    ""        
    write-host "Complete!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have solved it by using the counters as well. Here is the code :

    $InputFile = 'C:\Temp\list.txt'
$addresses = get-content $InputFile
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $InputFile
$TotalIPs = 0
$Ctr = 5

while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){ $TotalIPs++ }
write-Host $TotalIPs
write-host    ""    
write-Host "Executing nslookup query for all ..."    

While($Ctr)
{
    foreach($address in $addresses) 
    {
        ## Progress bar
        $i++

        ## End progress bar
        try 
        {
            [system.net.dns]::resolve($address) | Select HostName,AddressList
        }
        catch 
        {
            Write-host "$address was not found. $_" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }
    $i=0

    write-host    ""            
    write-Host "Pinging each address..."
    foreach($address in $addresses) {
    ## Progress bar

    $j++
    $percentdone2 = (($j / $TotalIPs) * 100)
    $percentdonerounded2 = "{0:N0}" -f $percentdone2

    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing pings" -CurrentOperation "Pinging IP: $address (IP $j of $TotalIPs)" -Status "$percentdonerounded2% complete" -PercentComplete $percentdone2

    ## End progress bar
    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $address -Count 2 -Quiet ) 
        {  
            write-Host "$address responded" -ForegroundColor Green 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Write-Warning "$address does not respond to pings"              
        }  
    }
    $j = 0

    write-host    ""        
    write-host "Complete!"
    $Ctr--
}
```